# Java: detecting type of Object returned

Tags: java, swing, exception, casting, classcastexception

Is there a way to convert an unknown type of Object to an integer?
Well, my current code is:

```
ImageIcon question = new ImageIcon("D:\\Project Pics\\orange QMark 1 (small).jpeg");
String[] options = { "Numbers", "Alphabets", "Both" };

    JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,"What type of array are you sorting?", "Array Type",JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE, question, options, null);
```

How can I know or detect what type of object it is returning? I'm getting a ClassCastException when I do this:

```
int code = (int) JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,"What type of array are you sorting?", "Array Type",JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE, question, options, null);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The overloaded `showInputDialog` method you are using expects an `Object[]` as a arguemnt (which it uses for a combo box), for which it will return an `Object`. That object is one of the selected values in the array you provided.

In your current case, it is a String array, so all the values will be String. The only possible return values are the ones you have in the array. If for instance you have something  like

```
Object[] options = { "1", 2, true };
```

Then you would have to check `instanceof` to see what the type is, before you can cast. For instance

```
Object returnValue = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(...);
if (returnValue instanceof Integer) {
    Integer intValue = (Integer)returnValue;
}
```

As for how you are currently trying to cast int to the return value, I don't get it. The only possible return values are `{ "Numbers", "Alphabets", "Both" }`. Why you are trying to cast one of those values to int, I have no idea. Maybe provide a little more context as to what you are actually trying to achieve